# Can I use a precompiled serialization DLL with protobuf-net.Enyim NetTranscoder

Tags: protobuf-net, enyim.caching

protobuf-net       v2.0.0.602
protobuf-net.Enyim v1.0

I have a type model created via `RuntimeTypeModel.Create()` `.Add()` `.AddSubType()` and `.SetSurrogate()`.

I use a console program to `.Compile()` and create a serialization.dll used in my solution.

I also use Cocuhbase/Memcached via Enyim.

I would like to use my serialization.dll with the NetTranscoder provided with the protobuf-net.Enyim library.

Is that possible?

Comment: If anyone with enough rep could add a [protobuf-net-enyim] tag that would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: I don't think the extra tag would help, in all honestly

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just configure `RuntimeTypeModel.Default` (with `Add` / `AddSubType` / `SetSurrogate` etc) at the start of the application?

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks. I was approaching the problem badly. I can setup the RuntimeTypeModel.Default when the container starts and that should allow me to create the type model I need for serialization to/from couchbase.

Comment: so that we're clear: does configuring `RuntimeTypeModel.Default` solve the problem for you?

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, by setting up `RuntimeTypeModel.Default` when I am installing components in my container I am able to use protobuf-net-enyim with the `NetTranscoder`.